# Why is the set of all algebraic numbers closed under basic arithmetic operations?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know this set is closed under these operations but I need the proof of it. Firstly I tried to prove it by using direct proof, contradiction and mathematical induction but I failed. Then I thought that if I show this set is also a field, then it means this set is closed because of the definition of field. But by using axioms of field, I cannot show this is a field since I must use the property of fields which is closedness that I want to show. Now I have a point, but I need some help. There is a theorem which says all finite integral domains are fields. So, if I show this set is finite integral domain, then it means this is a field and it is closed under these operations. I don't know whether I am on the right way or not. I am so confused. Is there anyone who can help and brighten me?

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is a much more general theorem about `integral ring extensions`:

> Let $R\longrightarrow S$ be a $R$-algebra. An element $\alpha\in S$ is integral over $R$ if and only if $R[\alpha]$ is a finite $R$-module.

There results that the sum and the product of two integral elements (in particular, in the case of an extension field, the sum and the product of two algebraic elements) are
integral elements.

Furthermore, for an extension field $E/K$, the minimal polynomial $f(X))0$ of an algebraic element is irreducible, hence has a non-zero constant term, so that, if $f(\alpha)=a_0+a_1\alpha+\dots a_n\alpha^n=0$ ($a_0, a_n\ne 0$), we deduce
$$\frac{f(\alpha)}{\alpha^n}=a_0\Bigl(\frac1{\alpha}\Bigr)^n+a_1\Bigl(\frac1{\alpha}\Bigr)^{n-1}+\dots a_n=0.$$
Therefore, $\dfrac1{\alpha}$ is algebraic.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the set of all the algebraic elements over a field $K$, then there are simple lemmas showing you that if $\alpha,\beta$ are algebraic element in some extension of $K$, then $\alpha+\beta,\alpha\beta,\alpha^{-1}$ are algebraic too.

There are many proofs for these facts. The classical constructive proofs used resultants to determine polynomials vanishing on the right elements. Otherwise, you can argue as following. Suppose $\alpha,\beta$ are algebraic over $K$; then the extension $K(a,b)$ is algebraic, hence finite. So in particular every element in it will be algebraic over $K$. In particular, $\alpha+\beta,\alpha\beta,\alpha^{-1}\in K(a,b)$